# httpd-devel for centos 4.6

Tags: centos

I have an old server and I need http-devel pacakge for Centos 4.6 distribution. 
Basically because I need to install php from sources but apxs command is missing.

Is there any public archive on the internet of old linux distributions or where could I get the old rpm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get them directly from CentOS.

http://vault.centos.org/4.6/